# downloading Parse images into an array then append them into another array

Tags: ios, arrays, image, swift, parse-platform

What i'm attempting to do is to download a series of images from parse (up to 5), converting them into UIImages then appending each image into a tempArray then finally adding them into a master array.

Everything gets downloaded and converted into a UIImage because I "println()" then UIImage and something is there. But when I try to add the 5 images into a master array it doesn't work. It prints as if there is nothing in the temporary array.

I then want to show these times into a table which as the images. When I download only one image and directly append it to the masterArray it works fine. Here is my code.

```
photoQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
if error == nil {
    for object in objects!{

        var tempImageArray = [UIImage]() // will hold temp Images which will be appended to masterImageArray

        if object.objectForKey("imageOne") != nil {
            var imageDataOneToDL = object["imageOne"] as! PFFile
            imageDataOneToDL.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imgOneData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    if let imgOne = UIImage(data: imgOneData!){
                        self.tempDoodleArray.append(imgOne)//append to temp array
                        println(imgOne) // image there
                    }
                }
            })
        }

        if object.objectForKey("imageTwo") != nil {
            var imageDataTwoToDL = object["imageTwo"] as! PFFile
            imageDataTwoToDL.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imgTwoData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    if let imgTwo = UIImage(data: imgTwoData!){
                        tempImageArray.append(imgTwo) // append to temp array
                        println(imgTwo) // image there
                    }
                }
            })
        }

        if object.objectForKey("imageThree") != nil {
            var imageDataThreeToDL = object["imageThree"] as! PFFile
            imageDataThreeToDL.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imgThreeData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    if let imgThree = UIImage(data: imgThreeData!){
                        tempImageArray.append(imgThree) // append to temp array
                        println(imgThree) // image there
                    }
                }
            })
        }

        //DO imageFour
        //Do imageFive

        self.masterImageArray.append(tempImageArray) // temp Images to master array --- nothing is showing in tempImageArray
    }
}
}
```

If i'm creating temp array of UIImage in the for-loop should be something in that array towards the end? I've been struggling with this for the past 2 days. Can someone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the tempImageArray before the loop and add it to the masterImageArray after the loop.

```
var tempImageArray = [UIImage]()

for object in objects!{
    // add image to tempImageArray
}

self.masterImageArray.append(tempImageArray)
```

You might have done this intentionally for testing purposes but for "imageOne", you are currently adding it to tempDoodleArray instead of tempImageArray.